# Rest api doc hal explorer with Spring webflux not working

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-webflux, doc

I use Spring boot with webflux in aplication properties adding thos properties makes not working the Rest api doc explorer HAL or an other

```
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
```

Tested with a demo application, before putting this configuration we have acces, and then it is not working.

How can we make working the hal explorer with rest api ?

we have a 404 not found
[image]